# android - requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) exception

Tags: android, android-fullscreen

I am setting a specific activity full screen when the use hits a START button.

In this case the `showStopButton()` is called .

It's running fine. But if I insert

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

then it crashes , stating that it should be call before adding content.

How should I handle it to set `NO_TITLE` w the `FULL_SCREEN` ??

```
    private void showStopButton(){

    // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.content).requestLayout();

    // handle element visibility
((Button)findViewById(R.id.stopButton)).setEnabled(false);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.stopButton)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ((SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.resetButton)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.saveButton)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

I have the reverse process when the START button is redisplayed , and it's running back fine
In this case I remove the fullscreen mode

```
     private void showStartButton(){

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.content).requestLayout();
        ....
    }
```

Comment: you have to call "requestWindowFeature" before the "setContentView()".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(
    final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Make this activity, full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // Hide the Title bar of this activity screen
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // MORE INIT STUFF HERE...
    //img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRandom);
    //btnRandom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRandom);
}
```

Comment: yes this is working , in the onCreate() method... but I am trying to hide it from within the showStop() method...  I found the solution after sleeping a while...

Answer (score 4):

it's so simple ...  I just need to hide the ActionBar...  then show it when back to standard screen...

```
   private void showStopButton(){
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();
        getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.content).requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 4):

Use -public class MainActivity extends Activity- instead of -public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity-

Answer (score 1):

Try this one......

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        context = this;

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

before

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.your activity);
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   ...
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); 
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

I used the above codes in the example of police car lights and siren.When the application is started, the light animation starts automatically and the siren sounds in the background.

Source : [Android police lights & siren](https://eksi30.com/android-police-light-siren-example/)

[image]