# Android Application in full screen

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to open my application in full screen by adding the code below to the section indicated in the code below that:

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

In order to open my application in full screen, I've tried to insert the code above in the onCreate method in the code below, however when I run the application I get the error that the application has stopped unexpectedly.

```
package com.example.expandinglists;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;





//import android.R;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
HashMap<String, List<String>> Movies_category;
List<String> Movies_List;
ExpandableListView Exp_list;
MoviesAdapter adapter;

private final String TAG = "DemoButton";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   **//inputting code here**

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Exp_list = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_list);
    Movies_category = DataProvider.getInfo();
    Movies_List = new ArrayList<String>(Movies_category.keySet());
    adapter = new MoviesAdapter(this, Movies_category, Movies_List);
    Exp_list.setAdapter(adapter);




    //Button functionality: From Here
    setupMessageButton();
    //Button Functionality: Till Here
}


private void setupMessageButton() {
    // Button Functionality
    //1. Get Reference to the button
    Button messageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplayMessage);



    //2. Button on Click Listener to run the button related code
    //View.OnClickListener myListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
    messageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            //Log.i(TAG, "You Clicked the Button");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Clicked it",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
        }           
    });
    //Use the button class create above
    //messageButton.setOnClickListener(myListener);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

**Update**

Not sure if it helps, but below is the log from the logcat.

Comment: You also have to provide exception message(log in logcat). Surely, then someone here will help you :)

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21354365/android-requestwindowfeaturewindow-feature-no-title-exception

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply @Xcihnegn. The seems to make sense (I'm saying makes sense, since I'm not an experienced developer), however I still get the error that the application crashed unexpectedly. Could it be something wrong with the development environment ?

Comment: Can you copy the error from `Logcat` and show

Comment: @Xcihnegn; log file details below:

1.FATAL EXCEPTION: main 2.java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.expandinglists/com.example.expandinglists.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content 3.at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663) 4.at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679) 5.at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

Comment: `requestFeature() must be called before adding content` means call before `setContentView(...)`

Answer (score 0):

write following code in sequence:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Remove TitleBar
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Remove notification bar.
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, @Hiren Vaghela, I did try your code, however I still get the error that application has stopped unexpectedly. the code you supplied looks fine. Could it be something from the development environment ?

Thanks in advance,

J

Comment: You can replace ActionBarActivity to Activity then your problem solve.

Comment: hi #joebegborg07 If you solve your problem using my solution then please checked as correct ans on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved my issue. I extended my application to **Activity** rather to **ActivityActionBar**:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
...
}
```

Thanks for your help,

J