# Android app failed to launch

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to hide title bar of my app but if I try to add following code & while launching it immediately stops & shows Unfortunately app(app name) has stopped. If I remove following line from code then it works.

Following code I am using onCreate() Method

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

I just want to hide title bar. Is there anything wrong with code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
    }
```

UPDATE ERROR

```
Error:Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Error:Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
```

Comment: share the error details

Comment: getTitle bar as you are getting webView and set visibility gone

Comment: Have you search for [other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21354365/android-requestwindowfeaturewindow-feature-no-title-exception)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**In your 'MainActivity.java'**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.cnn.com");
    }
}
```

**And in `android manifest`**

select / set theme as `NoTitleBar`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `requestWindowFeature` before the `setContentView()`

Like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
}
```

Comment: After this apk is not created.

Comment: Do you see any errror?

Comment: clean and rebuild your project

Comment: Same error coming. App is not building. Could it be a memory problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your error stack trace:

> Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

You have to call requestWindowFeature before the setContentView()

so your problem is the following line of your code
`this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

it needs to be called before

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

so to say like this:

`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
}`

thx to Nongthonbam Tonthoi - I just wannted it to be more clear how get rid of future problems ;-)